# Strange VPN problems in new home network

Tags: vpn, openvpn, home-networking

I have a very strange problem after I moved apartments. I'm working remotely from Japan using a OpenVPN connection and connect to my work computer via Remote Desktop. I recently moved apartments. In the old apartment everything works perfectly fine. And right now, when I'm using my mobile data everything works fine. But when I'm using my new internet, I have very strange problems:

The VPN connection is successfully created and I can connect via Remote Desktop. Until yesterday, this part work without any problems. Since today, I will loose connection to Remote Desktop after about 1 minute. Always without exception.
This is when using the Parallels Remote Desktop Client. When using the Windows Remote Desktop Client, I can't connect at all.

I can not connect to any internal websites of my company from my host computer. I can ping and traceroute them and it looks fine.

But when I make a hotspot with my phone and use the local data, everything works perfectly fine.

The apartment has a wall-embedded Ruijie AP180-AC Router. I tried switching between AP mode and router mode, but it makes no difference.

I would really appreciate any help because I do not have the slightest idea what is going on here. Seems like a very strange behaviour to me, but also my networking knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Try lowering MTU on the VPN link. Also check for packet loss. What protocol does your OpenVPN connection use, TCP or UDP?

Comment: @DanielB omg thank you so much it was actually the MTU size!

Comment: @DanielB I know it fixed the OP's issue, but why would the MTU size matter with OpenVPN, as high MTU values [`48000`] is recommended for OpenVPN for optimal throughput _(you don't want MTUs ~`1400` with OpenVPN, as it really hampers throughput)_. Would it be an issue because the OpenVPN server isn't being run on the router and is instead being run on a downstream machine?

Comment: @JW0914 Check [this Q/A on Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/73261). IP Fragmentation is bad and should be avoided. On WAN network even “at all costs”. Not sure what a large OpenVPN MTU is supposed to accomplish, but I guess reliability over high-latency WAN, possibly with packet loss, isn’t it. // Unfortunately, because OP did not provide the protocol type, an exhaustive answer isn’t possible.

Comment: @DanielB Since OpenVPN encapsulates TLS packets within UDP packets, higher MTU values in OpenVPN are similar to ethernet jumbo frames _(MTU on physical adapters should match or be slightly lower than the ISP's - e.g. ~`1450` range)_ - see [_Tweaked Setup_](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Gigabit_Networks_Linux) for how drastically it affects throughput by increasing the virtual adapter's MTU _(a two-fold increase with AES256, which is why OpenVPN configs should always be tuned and not generic)_. OpenVPN's MTU is often confused with the physical adapter MTU - they're not the same.

Comment: @JW0914 Tunnel MTU may not be the same, but is very much related to real MTU. This will result in massively fragmented packets on the real network. The guide says all that under “Explanation”. It also says this may not work outside a LAN network. This could absolutely kill routers if they attempt to re-fragment.

Comment: @DanielB I did see that when combined with WAN connections other than cable/DSL/fiber, it may not always be a possibility - I've been [running](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN) a tunnel MTU of `48000` for almost a decade with AES256 on OpenWrt, then later with Sophos UTM, and have never had an issue on any of the Linksys WRT routers used for OpenWrt or with the custom router box I use with a SuperMicro A1SRi-2758F server board for running Sophos via ESXi. It's def not a one-size-fits-all approach

Comment: Maybe best asked on : https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @DanielB, since the comment fixed the issue, why not expand on it (as was done in comments) and make it an answer that can help others? (You might show directions for optimizing MTU size.)

Comment: @DanielB Sorry for the incomplete answer. I was just too happy that it was working again. It was quite frustrating for two days.
UDP is used for the OpenVPN connection. The MTU was set by OpenVPN to 1380 (couldn't find anything in the config file, so I assume it is the default value from OpenVPN) and I adjusted it down to 1200 with `ifconfig utun6 mtu 1200 up`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you experience mysterious network problems (some things work, others don’t, stuff starts and stops working seemingly at random, connections randomly fail), the problem is often with (heavy) packet loss. Fragmented IP packets are a potential contributing factor to packet loss. To not have fragmented packets, the MTU must be lowered.

This also applies to some VPN tunnels, like OpenVPN. Because your tunnel is UDP-based, the tunnel connection cannot recover from lost packets. The packet loss also manifests inside the tunnel. Some software reacts poorly to packet loss.

With OpenVPN, there are multiple ways to address this, all of which go into the client configuration file:

- Use either `link-mtu 1300` or `tun-mtu 1300` (but not both) to explicitly lower the MTU
- Use `mtu-disc yes` to enable Path MTU Discovery, but this apparently only works on Linux
- Use `mtu-test` to enable a different MTU discovery mechanism that may work on all operating systems but takes a long time
- Use `fragment 1300` to have OpenVPN do fragmentation internally

Furthermore, `mssfix 1300` could be used to make tunneled TCP connections behave, but that’s just a performance optimization.

Selecting a limit that is too low for any of these options could seriously affect throughput inside the tunnel. The OpenVPN manual suggests 1300 as a starting point when experiencing issues.

---

You can read some more about IP fragmentation [on this Q/A over at Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/73261).

---

You should still check your regular internet connection for notable packet loss. A few percent are tolerable, but once it gets to 10-20% or even higher, it becomes very annoying. If you experience excessive packet loss, there could be a bad connection somewhere. With DSL, this could be bad/old in-house telephone wiring. Cable is also sensitive to this, plus stuff like impedance mismatch, missing termination or bad signal amplifiers.